# How do I create a histogram in R with logarithmic x and y axes?

Tags: r, histogram, lattice

So I have a vector of integers, `quotes`, which I wish to see whether it observes a power law distribution by plotting the frequency of data points and making both the x and y axes logarithmic. However, I am not quite sure how to accomplish this in R. I can currently create a histogram using

```
hist(quotes, breaks = max(quotes))
```

But the axes are all linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do this, but this (basically) works:

```
data = rnorm(1000,0,1)
r <- hist(log(data))
plot(r$breaks[-1],log(r$counts))
```

EDIT: Better solution:

```
r <- hist(data)
plot(r$breaks[-1], r$counts, log='xy', type='h')
# or alternatively:
barplot(r$counts, log="y", col="white", names.arg=r$breaks[-1])
```

The barplot version doesn't have a transformed x axis for reasons that will become clear if you try it with the x axis transformed.

Comment: a histogram is just a scatterplot. You can use `type='h'` to make this into a thin bar chart. Also, I left out the $breaks in the second version, but I think you still want them. Modified my response.

Comment: Aha, thanks, that works well! By the way, what is the reason behind removing the first element from breaks?

Comment: The breaks vector is one element longer than the counts vector. Just lopping off one end or other from the vector works but is sort of lazy: what you really want is the median value between each pair of "breaks." I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader ;)

Comment: What does the r$breaks[-1] do?

Comment: @PhilGoetz I already answered this in the comments. Look at the comment directly above yours.